# Python || IDE not recognizing import

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?
Trying to import `dataB` into `main` but the IDE is not recognizing it. 
I'm clearly doing something wrong.
Both files are in the same directory.
~~`Unresolved reference "dataB"`  `Unresolved reference "authenticate"`  `Unresolved reference "identity"`~~
[image: main.py]
[image: dataB.py]

Comment: Try `from tinyleef.dataB import *`

Comment: VSCode always runs your python code from the opened folder, so from the `Flask-Project` folder.  so the import mentioned by JackSong should work for your IDE, you can also do `from .dataB import *` adding a period to make it a relative import.

Comment: That worked thank you. I'm using Intellij

Comment: Mark the directory as source, that usually works for me